# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB in INFORMATICA PowerCenter

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I get the below error while trying to run a session in informatica.

```
ERROR  10/11/2023 2:56:21 PM  node02  READER_1_1_1  RR_4035  SQL Error [ ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB
```

I have the below SQL query added in the source qualifier to extract data from CLOB in the source.

```sql
select objectid,db_instance_seq, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA,'\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|',1,column_value,NULL,1) AS TEXT,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA,'\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|',1,column_value,NULL,2) AS SVCFID, 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA,'\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|',1,column_value,NULL,3) AS AX_TYP_CD,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA,'\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|',1,column_value,NULL,4) AS VALUE
from   TEST
       cross join table(
          cast(
           multiset(
             select level
             from   dual  
             where DATA LIKE '%RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint%' 
             connect by level <= regexp_count(
                                   DATA,
                                   '\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|'
                                 )
                   ) 
           as sys.odcinumberlist
         )
       )
```

Comment: It seems like an issue between Source Qualifier (SQ) and the data actually read from DB. Can you paste the exact SQL query and the SQ?

Comment: @Maciejg - The query provided above is the exact query used in the SQL. It is running in Oracle SQL Developer tool while throwing the error in Informatica PC.

Comment: The task is to extract the data from the CLOB column in the Oracle source and load it in the Oracle target.

Comment: I understand that the query works. The query works and returns a dataset different than expected by Source Qualifier, it seems. Please show the SQ definition.

Comment: @Maciejg - In the source definition, the field 'objectid' is number(p,s) , 'db_instance_seq' is number(p,s) and 'data' is clob. In the SQ, the  'objectid' is decimal, 'db_instance_seq' is decimal and 'data' is nstring.

Comment: First of all I'm asking about the Source Qualifier. And I'd rather see the definition. From what you say it seems as if the SQL returns 6 fields and Source Definition has just 4. And the error clearly states that where NUMBER is expected, SQ got CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than regular expressions, you can use simple string functions (which are much faster) and a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc (objectid, db_instance_seq, data, spos, dpos1, dpos2, dpos3, epos) AS (
  SELECT objectid,
         db_instance_seq,
         data,
         INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', 1),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', 1) + 34, 1),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', 1) + 34, 2),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', 1) + 34, 3),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', 1) + 34, 4)
  FROM   test
UNION ALL
  SELECT objectid,
         db_instance_seq,
         data,
         INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', epos + 1),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', epos + 1) + 34, 1),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', epos + 1) + 34, 2),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', epos + 1) + 34, 3),
         INSTR(data, '|', INSTR(data, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint', epos + 1) + 34, 4)
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  spos > 0
  AND    epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY objectid, db_instance_seq SET order_id
SELECT objectid,
       db_instance_seq,
       SUBSTR(data, spos + 1, dpos1 - spos - 1) AS text1,
       SUBSTR(data, dpos1 + 1, dpos2 - dpos1 - 1) AS text2,
       SUBSTR(data, dpos2 + 1, dpos3 - dpos2 - 1) AS text3,
       SUBSTR(data, dpos3 + 1, epos - dpos3 - 1) AS text4
from   rsqfc
WHERE  spos > 0
AND    epos > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (objectid, db_instance_seq, data) AS
  SELECT 1,
         1,
         EMPTY_CLOB()
         || '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint - AAAAA|BBBB|CCCC|DDDD|' || CHR(10)
         || 'XXXX|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint - EEEEE|F||H|I|J|K' || CHR(10)
  FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| OBJECTID | DB_INSTANCE_SEQ | TEXT1 | TEXT2 | TEXT3 | TEXT4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint - AAAAA | BBBB | CCCC | DDDD |
| 1 | 1 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint - EEEEE | F | *null* | H |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/z15Rg2Za)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Kindly let me know what modifications I need to make if I need to extract the subsequent 3 values (which are separated by |). Example - |BBBB|CCCC|DDDD|

Comment: @AR91 Updated (just find the position of each of the delimiter and then get the sub-string between those delimiters).

Comment: @ MT0 - Hi there !! I wanted to check with you regarding the performance optimization of the query. Since CLOB does not support parallel processing, the time taken to process huge volumes of data (millions) is high. Kindly let me know if there are any other alternatives to SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY / CONNECT BY that would improve the performance. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.